# How to pass a database connection to my http handlers?

Tags: database, haskell, scope, monads

Here's a simplified version of my REST API. I'm using [Scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) and [RethinkDB](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb).

Right now I have to pass the database connection into each route handler so they can `run` the query (see `coursesAll`). With more than 10 routes this would get really annoying. I know I could define the route handlers inside the main method, and the connection handle `h` would be in scope, but that doesn't scale either.

I would like to be able to define top-level functions so I can put them in different files. How can I clean this code up?

A part of my brain knows monads can do this, but how?  Scotty uses the `ActionM` monad, and RethinkDB has a monad too, but I'm not sure how to combine them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Web.Scotty
import Courses.Course
import qualified Database.RethinkDB as R
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Courses.Connection

main :: IO ()
main = do
    h <- connectDb
    scotty 3000 $ do
        get "/" info
        get "/courses" (coursesAll h)

info :: ActionM ()
info = text "Courses v1"

coursesAll :: R.RethinkDBHandle -> ActionM ()
coursesAll h = do
    courses <- liftIO $ R.run h coursesTable
    json $ (courses :: [Course])


connectDb :: IO (R.RethinkDBHandle)
connectDb = do
    connection <- R.connect "localhost" 28015 Nothing
    let connectionDb = R.use connection (R.db "courses")
    return connectionDb
```

---

**UPDATE:** RethinkDB ended up not being relevant. Really, I want to know how to pass global config into my routes. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Web.Scotty
import Web.Scotty.Trans

import Data.Text.Lazy
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Config = Config Text

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let config = Config "Hello World"
    -- how to I make this line work?
    scottyT 3000 id id routes

routes :: ScottyT Text (ReaderT Config IO) ()
routes = do
    get "/" info

info :: ActionT Text (ReaderT Config IO) ()
info = do
    -- this part seems like it works!
    Config message <- lift ask
    text $ "Info: " `append` message
```

Comment: It looks like there is an ActionT monad transformer for Scotty. Can I use that to do the job? https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/blob/master/Web/Scotty/Trans.hs

Comment: I haven't used scotty or rethinkdb before, but I would think that if you use `ActionT Text WhateverRethinkDBMonadIsBecauseHackageIsDown` as your monad, you should be fine.  Most of the functions I saw in scotty operated on the `ActionT` transformer with the only requirement being that you have a `Monad` or `MonadIO`

Comment: Ok, so RethinkDB doesn't have a monad. But I don't really need one. I just need to be able to define `Actions` and have access to an implied `RethinkDBHandle`. So it's kind of like the `State` monad but I don't even need to modify anything. If anyone feels brave enough to post sample code it would be much appreciated

Comment: You could use the `ReaderT` monad transformer then.  If I get time I'll try it out (again, never used scotty or rethink before, so I'd have to get them installed and working)

Comment: I just updated the example again. Really close. How do I bootstrap this to get the ScottyT / ReaderT thing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with your updated question, the only thing you need is to provide the two runner functions to `scottyT`. So let's look at the signature

```
scottyT 
  :: (Monad m, MonadIO n)    
  => Port    
  -> (forall a. m a -> n a) 
  -> (m Response -> IO Response)    
  -> ScottyT e m ()  
  -> n ()
```

`m` is the monad you want to embed into the `ActionT` stack and `n` is the result monad you want out when you run `scottyT`.

In your case `m` is `ReaderT Config IO` and `n` is simply `IO`.

The function `(forall a. m a -> n a)` is a function that convert any `ReaderT Config IO a` computation into `IO a` which we can easily do with [`runReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:runReaderT). So let's define

```
let readerToIO ma = runReaderT ma config
```

Next we need a function to turn `m Response` to `IO Response` but since in this case `n` is the same as `IO` we can just reuse the above `readerToIO` function. Thus

```
main = do
    let config = Config "Hello World"
        readerToIO ma = runReaderT ma config
    scottyT 3000 readerToIO readerToIO routes
```